# Can anyone identify this aircraft in the AMARG area of Davis Monthan?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Anyone has an idea what this thing in AMARG area of Davis Monthan could be?

[image: Unknown aircraft Davis Monthan]

Googlemaps link: https://www.google.com/maps/@32.1512545,-110.843407,25m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en

Comment: Another [angle](http://i.imgur.com/tpBd9lk.jpg), from [here](http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread1082990/pg2).

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, a close friend of mine pointed to these two very interesting articles on the topic:

http://foxtrotalpha.jalopnik.com/a-new-angle-on-this-shadowy-stealth-f-a-18-hornet-conce-1727910676

http://aviationweek.com/awin/super-hornet-stealth-test-rig-seen

Comment: please post here the relevant informations, links can rot and this answer would then be useless.

Comment: D/V until/unless you edit your answer to include enough information within the answer itself. FYI, at my current location, I cannot go to the jalopnik site, as it has issues, and the aviationweek site is a paywall.